# Showing convergence or a recursive sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Show that the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ defined by $x_1=3/4$ and $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n^2+x_n}{2}$ for $n\geq 1$ is convergent. Evaluate the limit of the sequence.

---

I was trying to prove the sequence is a Cauchy sequence and therefore convergent, but I couldn't. I think proving it's Cauchy might be over complicating things. Any input is welcome!

Comment: Have you made a numerical simulation to know what the limit is ?

Comment: No, I haven't. @JeanMarie

Comment: You might want to try to apply the Banach-Picard fixed point theorem on the function $f : x \mapsto 1/2 \cdot (x^2 + x)$ on an interval that would contain $3/4$ and is stable under $f$. I don't know if you've seen the general theorem, but since you're dealing with a recursive sequence on $\mathbb{R}$ you've probably seen the particular version you need.

Comment: So please do it. It should become a reflex when you have such a question.

Comment: Show that the sequence is bounded and monotonic.

Comment: Don't you know that the limit, if it exists, is a solution to quadratic equation $x=\frac{x^2+x}{2}$ ?

Comment: draw a graph of $y=\frac{x^2+x}{2}$ and $y=x$ and play

Comment: @Fred Thanks! Forgot about the monotone convergence theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $0<x_1<1$ and $0<x_n<1 \implies 0<x_{n+1}<x_n$ by induction the sequence is both decreasing and bounded, and by the monotone convergence theorem it has a limit. Call it L. Taking the limit in the definition of the sequence gives
$$
L = \frac{L^2+L}2 \implies  L=0 \text{ or } 1.
$$
Since the sequence is decreasing, $L=0$.